# Interpolation with entire function

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there any simple  way to construct an entiere function $f$ such that :
$$\forall p \in {\mathbb N} \quad f(2^p)=(-1)^p$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [Weierstrass products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem), for each integer $k$ we can find an entire function $f_k$ such that $f_k(2^j)=0$ if $k\neq j$ and $f_k(2^k)=(-1)^k2^k$. Define $f:=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}2^{-k}f_k$. Using the relation about elementary factors, we can see that the convergence of this series is uniform over compact sets. Hence this defines an entire function which does the job.

Comment: Thank you. I am not convinced of the simplicity of the uniform convergence proof. In fact I found a general statement (Mittag Lefler) that respond to this interpolation problem in the general case. See: http://www.joensuu.fi/matematiikka/kurssit/complex/luku6.pdf . However I am still trying for another proof avoiding major theorems.

Answer (score 6):

Typically, one uses both the [Weierstrass factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem) and [Mittag-Leffler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem) theorem to prove the existence of an entire function $f$ such that $f(z_n)=w_n$ for given $z_n\to\infty$ and given $w_n$.

1. Get an entire function $g$ with a simple zero at every $z_n$ (by Weierstrass).
2. Get a meromorphic function $h$ with principal part $w_n(g'(z_n)(z-z_n))^{-1}$ at every $z_n$ (by Mittag-Leffler)
3. Let $f=gh$: this is an entire function and $f(z_n)=w_n$.

---

But if you want to avoid heavy-duty theorems, see the article [*On Entire Function Interpolation*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2370666) by I. M. Sheffer, American Journal of Mathematics Vol. 49, No. 3 (Jul., 1927), pp. 329-342 which offers a more elementary proof of the existence of an entire function with prescribed values at positive integers.

Comment: I do not understand step 3, you could be more specific.